# Can tvOS simulator work as an Airplay receiver?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

Can tvOS simulator work as an Airplay receiver? 
Just like a normal Apple TV hardware device, receiving the Airplay video and play it back on the simulator screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Apple TV Simulator can't be an Airplay receiver.

If you want to present your iPhone screen in your Macbook, you can use quickTime Player to make a screen record. And you can "airplay" iPhone screen in your MacBook.

Just like this:
[image]